# Delete all uncommitted entities in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-data

Suppose I insert several entities in the database using coreData. I did not save. How to remove all inserted entities, which not saved, if I do not have references to them?

Okay, how i see, i can't use `[context rollback]` when `context.undoManages` is `nil`? Thats bad.
But after `[context reset]` what should i do with all my references and objects? What will happen with my interface if they are uses in datasource? I get crash?

Answer (score 5):

This is the purpose of [`CoreData's`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1) [`NSManagedObjectContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) class. It allows you to perform your changes in a 'scratchpad' that is specific to whatever purpose you choose. If you want, you can `[context save]`. Or if you decide to toss the thing...

```
[context rollback];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[managedObjectContext rollback]
```

will revert all unsaved changes.

Comment: It is possible if `context.undoManager` is `nil` value?

Answer (score 1):

If you use parent/child NSManagedObjectContext's then you could just create new instance of NSManagedObjectContext and reassign its parent.

If you don't then you could make use of instance method **reset**:

**Docs**:
*reset*

Returns the receiver to its base state.

`- (void)reset`

All the receiver's managed objects are “forgotten.” If you use this method, you should ensure that you also discard references to any managed objects fetched using the receiver, since they will be invalid afterwards.